# Android: animate a view with setY()

Tags: android, android-animation, translate-animation

I want to animate a simple view, say for example a simple textview. I want to use translate animate the view.

Now what my requirement is, I want to make a method, say for example `slide(View v, float position)`. Which will take the view to animate and position till where it should be animated. And I will call that method from desired place in my code.

To accomplish this, I have tried something. I have made `MyTranslateAnimation` class as follow.

```
public class MyTranslateAnimation extends Animation {

private View mView;
private final float position;

public MyTranslateAnimation(View view, float position){

    mView = view;
    this.position = position;
}

@Override
protected void applyTransformation(float interpolatedTime, Transformation t) {
    mView.setY(position);
    mView.requestLayout();
}
```

}

Then I made a `textview` in `MainActivity.java` and set `onTouchListener` and then created this method `slide()` to do the task I described above.

Below is the code:
`onCreate():`

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    _root = (ViewGroup)findViewById(R.id.root);

    _view = new TextView(this);
    _view.setText("TextView!!!!!!!!");

    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(150, 50);
    layoutParams.leftMargin = 50;
    layoutParams.topMargin = 50;
    layoutParams.bottomMargin = -250;
    layoutParams.rightMargin = -250;
    _view.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);

    _view.setOnTouchListener(this);
    _root.addView(_view);
}
```

`slide():`

```
private void slide(View view, float position){
    Animation animation = new MyTranslateAnimation(view, position);
    animation.setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator());
    animation.setDuration(200);
    animation.start();
}
```

And as below I used `slide()` method:

```
public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
    final int X = (int) event.getRawX();
    final int Y = (int) event.getRawY();
    switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) view.getLayoutParams();
            _xDelta = X - lParams.leftMargin;
            _yDelta = Y - lParams.topMargin;
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            slide(view, 100);
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) view.getLayoutParams();
            layoutParams.leftMargin = X - _xDelta;
            layoutParams.topMargin = Y - _yDelta;
            layoutParams.rightMargin = -250;
            layoutParams.bottomMargin = -250;
            view.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
            break;
    }
    _root.invalidate();
    return true;
}
```

Also I don't want to use `nineoldandroid` library for this.
Any help regarding this is highly appreciated.

Comment: What is the problem with your code? It might help if you asked a question

Comment: So? is you code not running? Or its running but not animating? or anything else

Comment: @fractalwrench
@SrujanBarai , thanks for responding. Actually there was so many problems with this code. But after some research I got to know about `ObjectAnimator` so I used it and updated `slide()` method and after that it worked.
I posted it as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`slide():`

```
public void slide(float position){
    ObjectAnimator objectAnimator = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(overflow.get(), "translationY", position);
    objectAnimator.setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator());
    objectAnimator.setDuration(200);
    objectAnimator.start();
}
```